# Subtracting the difference between two time intervals in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to subtract the difference between two time intervals, e.g.:

I have

```
DECLARE FROM_TIME DATE = TO_DATE('03.12.2015:09:00','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI'),
        TO_TIME DATE = TO_DATE('03.12.2015:10:24','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI');
```

How do I get the difference (`01:24`) in time between `FROM_TIME` and `TO_TIME`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big can be difference? Hours\days\ more?

Comment: Start by subtracting one datetime from the other.  Then format the result.

Comment: Only hours and minutes. Can you give me an example please?